# How about iOS GCD Performance?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I invoke a method( named A) repeatedly about 3000 times per seconds, in A method, I allocate some resources and do something.

If I allocate and do something in A method directly, it works fine. But if I allocate and do something in a customed serial thread created by GCD like blow, it will crash

```
NSString *queueName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"com.realank.thread"];
dispatch_queue_t serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create([queueName cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], NULL);
dispatch_async(initMidMenu, ^{

// alloc and do something

});
```

So I think why it will crash is because the performance limit about GCD thread, is anybody know about it? Thanks very much~

Comment: Show the complete crash log.

Comment: Sorry, the crash root cause is concurrent race actually. I ask this question is because I can't find any document to describe the performance about GCD thread. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allocating a new dispatch queue when you call `dispatch_queue_create`. You must release it afterwards using `dispatch_release`as mentioned by Apple. Otherwise you'll run out of memory!!!

https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/1453030-dispatch_queue_create#return-value

You can get a reference to the newly created queue by the return value of the `dispatch_queue_create` method, and then release it afterwards.

Here's how Apple has mentioned it in their documentation.

> When your application no longer needs the dispatch queue, it should
>   release it with the dispatch_release function.